# Loganalytics workspace ID parameter template

Tags: json, azure, containers, azure-aks

I tried to create a container group and want to push those container logs in Loganalytics.

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01
location: eastus2
name: mycontainergroup003
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer003
    properties:
      environmentVariables: []
      image: fluent/fluentd
      ports: []
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  diagnostics:
    logAnalytics:
      workspaceId: /subscriptions/f446b796-978f-4fa0-8462-......../resourcegroups/v_deployment-docker_us/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/deployment-docker-logs
      workspaceKey: nEZSOUGe1huaCksRB2ahsFz/ibcaQr3WPdAHiLc............ 
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Now whenever I try to run :

```
az container create --resource-group rg-deployment-docker --name mycontainergroup003 --file .\azure-deploy-aci.yaml
```

then I would get the error as :

```
(InvalidLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId) The log analytics setting is invalid. WorkspaceId contains invalid character, e.g. '/', '.', etc.
Code: InvalidLogAnalyticsWorkspaceId
Message: The log analytics setting is invalid. WorkspaceId contains invalid character, e.g. '/', '.', etc.
```

Now I wish to create such parameter type with the help of parameter json file as mentioned in the URL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/resource-manager-workspace

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workspaceId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
}
```

Now I would run the below command:

```
az container create --resource-group rg-deployment-docker --name mycontainergroup003 --file .\azure-deploy-aci.yaml --parameters parameters.json
```

but getting the error as :

```
unrecognized arguments: --parameters parameters.json
```

It seems such arguments are invalid with az container create command. Can someone please suggest an alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the **log analytics workspace GUID** instead of passing the entire `ResourceId` in your Yaml file and also As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) **az container create** cmdlet doesn't have any parameter to pass `--parameter`flag.

Post making the above changes, i am able to deploy the container without any issues.

**Here is the sample screenshot output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I made a small typo , I corrected it and it`s working fine.

Comment: @UnicsSol , Glad to know that your issue got resolved